# Regex in PHP to find abc@xyz not working as expected

Tags: php, regex

I am struggling with some regex stuff using PHP.

**What do I want to achieve**

- I want to iterate through all files in a certain location
- If the file is a sql file (identified by the extension .sql) I want to open it and find all abc@xyz matches using regex

**What I achieved so far**

- go through all directories
- do some matching with regex but only the @xyz part

**What I would like some help with**

- *How can I change my regex to store abc@xyz instead of @xyz in the $matches Array?*

**The code**

```
<?php

$path = realpath('.');

$objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

# go through each file/directory
foreach($objects as $name => $object){
    #check if it is a sql file
    if (strpos($name,'.sql') > 0) {
    #open the file
        $file = file_get_contents($name);

        # check if the file could be succesfully read
        if ($file) {
            #if so we are looking for the @ sign identifying a db link
            if  (strpos($file,'@') > 0) {               


                # we found at least one @ sign, now go through the file again and again and again...
                $at_pos=0;
                while ($at_pos=strpos($file,'@',$at_pos+1)) {
                    echo "we got a db link in $name at position: $at_pos\n";

                    $result=preg_match("{\b\w*@\w*\b}",$file,$matches,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE,$at_pos);
                    print_r($matches);
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo "We could not open $name\n";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

**The sample test2.sql file**

```
-- thsis is a file with a db_link
select * from abc@db_link;

but look we also got Select * from ddks@db_link2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regex and parsing together strikes me as a really bad idea. You could use `preg_match_all` instead.

```
if (strpos($file,'@') > 0) {               

    # we found at least one @ sign, now find all matches
    preg_match_all('/\b([a-zA-Z_0-9]+@[a-zA-Z_0-9]+)\b/', $file, $matches)

}
```

The results are now in an array of name $matches, just iterate through it to view all the matches.

To read more about this function, read the documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: thanks do you know why I get the matches twice in my $matches array? 
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => abc@db_link
            [1] => ddks@db_link2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => abc@db_link
            [1] => ddks@db_link2
        )

)

Comment: Alright, I'm sitting on a train, so I'm a bit in and out of decent data roaming. Glad you got it working. I'll edit it with a link to the documentation for future viewers.